# Some problems about Liferay & Ldap

Tags: ldap, liferay

I integrate openldap in liferay.

Then Liferay import users from openldap.(It is successfully, some data was imported into db)

But when I login in liferay.

some exceptions happened.

Exceptions Information:

```
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowException: No workflow handler found for com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.model.MBDiscussion
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.java:80)
    at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.addMessage(MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.java:393)
    at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.addDiscussionMessage(MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.java:173)
    at com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.service.impl.MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.addDiscussionMessage(MBMessageLocalServiceImpl.java:132)
```

And I can't enter the index page .

It shows:

```
an-unexpected-system-error-occurred 
com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowException: No workflow handler found for com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.model.MBDiscussion
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem just now and I'm *not* using LDAP to authenticate users, so I thought I'd share what I found out. What I did was try to streamline Liferay by deactivating portlets we don't need. I added

```
<include>false</include>
```

to several portlets in `liferay-portlet.xml`. I found that removing the `message-boards` portlets this way breaks a lot of things in Liferay. I'd hazard a guess and say that there are some (undocumented) cross-dependencies in the core of Liferay to this message boards portlet or some of the other portlets.

Since I reactivated the portlet again, everything works fine.